# Finding Rogue Kitty

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Thoroughly annoyed that all the Stack Exchangers have forgotten about her and left her alone for several months with no attempt to help her with [Kitty's New Mission](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47396/kittys-new-mission), it seems Kitty has gone rogue.

Calls have not been answered for a few weeks and her bosses are beginning to despair of finding her...until they receive some postcards from her every few days.
The only message on them is 'I've had enough trying to solve your puzzles with no help-now you try and solve mine'.

Well,a few days after the fourth postcard arrives,she steps off the plane at a certain place-and is met by a set of unhappy bosses,who are keen to return her home for 'a discussion and debriefing'. Where did they find her?

Postcard 1

[image]

Postcard 2

[image]

Postcard 3

[image]

Postcard 4

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The four pictures show, in order,

> the Wiener Riesenrad in Vienna (capital of Austria);
>  the Atomium in Brussels (capital of Belgium);
>  a Greek flag painted on a wall in the UN Buffer Zone in Cyprus (this particular thing is in Nicosia, the capital);
>  the Tivoli Gardens in Copenhagen, capital of Denmark.

It's notable that

> these countries' names begin with A,B,C,D in order. Anything interesting about their last letters? AMSK, doesn't look like it. Second letters of country codes (at,be,cy,dk)? TEYK, also not obviously helpful. Second letters of country names (I'm really scraping the barrel here)? UEYE, also unhelpful.

They're all

> capital cities (hinting at capital letters? Hardly, since that just gives us ABCD). First letters of those cities, to go with the first letters of the countries? VBNC or WBNC, yet again not obviously helpful. The cities all have airports, and the question indicates that airports might be worth thinking of. Their codes are VIE, BRU, NIC, CPH which yet again seems unhelpful.

None of this cleverness is getting me anywhere, so let's try something more straightforward.

> Kitty is clearly visiting countries in alphabetical order, and so far they are all in Europe. The only country in Europe whose name begins with E is Estonia. So I'm guessing that her bosses found her getting off a plane at **Tallinn Airport in Estonia**.

Comment: Very nice - how did you know what the pictures were, particularly the 3rd one?

Comment: Reverse image search is a wonderful invention :-).

Comment: Ah, that figures. I was wondering if you were going from memory, which would explain the other 3.

Comment: I got 2 instantly from memory. I initially thought 1 was the London Eye. 3 and 4 I would never have got without reverse image search. (Well, unless searching for "greek flag painted on wall" or something of the kind finds it, which a very brief experiment suggests it doesn't.)

Comment: The onion dome in #4 misled me nicely, I was thinking it was Turkey or some such country.

Comment: @Phylyp, I think Gareth may have flipped the postcards over and checked the postmarks :-)

Comment: Ah you're too damn good for Kitty-she thought she'd hoodwinked you with the big Greek flag and the oniony domes. Will you have any more success managing to catch her again here?https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60129/finding-rogue-kitty-ii