# Finding Rogue Kitty II

Tags: cipher, knowledge

Having been met by a group of very unhappy bosses at

> Tallinn Airport in Estonia

Kitty is being 'returned' to the staff car when suddenly there is a commotion and she makes a run for it.

As they chase her, little old ladies are sent bouncing off into corners. 
Men are dodging around travelers wheeling bulky luggage trolleys and leaping over the pot plants she is lobbing into their path and trying to catch the clothes and accessories she is flinging off as she runs.

They manage to get to the departures lounge just as a 'convenient power cut' knocks out all the lighting, CCTV and screens.
All they have is a fetching hat and glasses that got grabbed as she legged it, a rather snazzy little zip-up black dress and this little code.

```
0 1 0 2 2 2

3 1 2 7 9 0

3 2 8 3 4 6

0 3 2 6 1 1

1 4 8 1 4 3

1 3 2 1 0 0

9 0 2 5 1 7

8 2 5 4 5 7

9 5 1 3 2 3

3 8 7 2 9 4
```

Can you work out where on Earth Kitty has headed for?

Comment: If the last puzzle is anything to go by, probably Helsinki or Paris :)

Comment: FRK (from the title) is the code for an airport in the Seychelles.. which has 10 letters, the code has 10 lines. I tried to decipher the message but didn't find how.

Comment: I hope those are actually **pot*ted*** plants—or else this is a rather unusually free spirited airport.